# Sorting a list of uneven lists based on the third column of the 1st row of each uneven list

Tags: python, list, sorting, date, datetime

I have a csv file where I group rows together if they share the same address. These groups contain around 1 - 10 rows. I need to sort these groups based on a date in the fourth column in the first row of each group.

Below is a pseudo illustration of my data and below that is my code.

```
list_of_parcel_groups = [ [ [ [0,1,2,11/22/2022],[0,1,2,01/01/2001] ] , [ [0,1,2,3/11/2022],[0,1,2,3/4/2016],[0,1,2,5/18/2011],[0,1,2,03/13/2009] ] , [ [0,1,2,5/13/2019],[0,1,2,4/20/2018],[0,1,2,7/13/1999] ] ]
```

I want to sort list_of_parcel_groups and append it to qualified so
that it looks like this...

```
qualified = [ [0,1,2,5/13/2019],[0,1,2,4/20/2018],[0,1,2,7/13/1999],[0,1,2,3/11/2022],[0,1,2,3/4/2016],[0,1,2,5/18/2011],[0,1,2,03/13/2009],[0,1,2,11/22/2022],[0,1,2,01/01/2001] ]
```

I am sorting based on the dates in

```
list_of_parcel_groups[0][0][3]
list_of_parcel_groups[1][0][3]
list_of_parcel_groups[2][0][3]


for i in range(len(list_of_parcel_groups)):
    if i == 0:
        string_input_with_date = list_of_parcel_groups[i][0][3]
        date = datetime.strptime(string_input_with_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        for item in list_of_parcel_groups[i]:
            qualified.append(item)
        continue
    
    string_input_with_date1 = list_of_parcel_groups[i][0][3]
    date1 = datetime.strptime(string_input_with_date1, "%m/%d/%Y")
    if (date1.date() <= date.date()):
        
        list_of_parcel_groups[i].reverse()
        for item in list_of_parcel_groups[i]:
            qualified.insert(0,item)
        list_of_parcel_groups[i].reverse()
        date = string_input_with_date = list_of_parcel_groups[i][0][3]
        date = datetime.strptime(string_input_with_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        continue
    if (date1.date() > date.date()):
        
        for item in list_of_parcel_groups[i]:
            qualified.append(item)
        date = string_input_with_date = list_of_parcel_groups[i][0][3]
        date = datetime.strptime(string_input_with_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I tried inserting each element of a group into index 0 of the array whenever it was earlier date than the previous date, and appending each row the group to the end of the array whenever the date was later than the previous date.

This did not give me the sorted result I was trying to do.

Also note each group is already sorted by date in the correct manner. This is why when I use the insert() function I reverse() the group and I reverse() it again after the insert() so that I can still use list_of_parcel_groups[i][0][3] to assign to the variable 'date' so that I can compare it to the date in the next loop.

Comment: Hi @Henry Mangelsdorf, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't paste your code/data as images - this makes it harder to test/edit and offer you a solution. Can you please paste your code (and a sample of your data) - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay I am sorry about that. I edited it with the code typed in but I am afraid the csv. data is just so large I can't fit it in the post.

Comment: I tried illustrating my data with a more simple example.

Comment: I've tried to interpret your raw data correctly and provided an answer that seems to yield your desired output. If that does what you're looking for, but you need more of an explanation of how the answer works, please ask and I'll expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've correctly understood the construction of your raw data, then this should give you what you're looking for - no?

```
from datetime import datetime

list_of_parcel_groups = [[[0,1,2,'11/22/2022'], [0,1,2,'1/01/2001']] , 
                         [[0,1,2,'3/11/2022'], [0,1,2,'3/04/2016'], [0,1,2,'5/18/2011'], [0,1,2,'3/13/2009']], 
                         [[0,1,2,'5/13/2019'], [0,1,2,'4/20/2018'], [0,1,2,'7/13/1999']]]

qualified = sorted(list_of_parcel_groups, key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0][3], "%m/%d/%Y"))

for sublist in qualified:
    print (sublist)

# Result:
    # [[0, 1, 2, '5/13/2019'], [0, 1, 2, '4/20/2018'], [0, 1, 2, '7/13/1999']]
    # [[0, 1, 2, '3/11/2022'], [0, 1, 2, '3/04/2016'], [0, 1, 2, '5/18/2011'], [0, 1, 2, '3/13/2009']]
    # [[0, 1, 2, '11/22/2022'], [0, 1, 2, '1/01/2001']]
```

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate you taking the time to answer this! I realized I almost came close to the answer you provided in my other attempts but didn't set it up right. Thank so much! Henry.